# Update usuário no Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Alguém sabe como podemos editar os dados de login de um usuário qualquer, cadastrado no Firebase pelo firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword,  através de um painel admin que não seja o do próprio Firebase? Ou seja, como posso editar os dados de um outro usuário no Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode editar as informações do usuário assim:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Se desejar alterar o login:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateEmail("user@example.com").then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Referência:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?hl=pt-br